# SharePoint content type?

Tags: sharepoint

What coluld be the way used by Sharepoint team to store content type data into SQL DB.
Is like that ?
**table : List1**

Col1 : Title

**.
.
.
.**

ContentType : MyContentType

**table : MyContentType**

Col1 : SomeCol

Col2 : SomeCol2

Answer (score 0):

Anything is possible. You shouldn't care about that. Whatever it is, it is something smart enough to efficiently work with inherited content types. If you really have to know, open your SPPS database (something _Content) and take a look at `dbo.ContentTypes`. 
Be warned that such action may void your support from Microsoft.

Comment: Taking a look or selecting won't void support with microsoft, but altering will for sure.

Comment: Its just like looking at the neighbor's wife, you only commit the crime if you actually touch it.

Comment: @F.Aquino ;-) maybe. A conference speaker, I think he was affiliated to Microsoft, told me that "If you make a lot of selects from content databases, you might alter the execution statistics". Dunno. Maybe, it makes sense.

Comment: Well you CAN get into nasty problems with select's, but not like you're not allowed: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/5-reasons-not-query-sp-db.aspx (Althought in article he states that you are not allowed, but i don't see that it's stated here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841057/en-us

Answer (score 0):

Content type definitions are not stored in the database in their own table.

Where they are stored, they are stored as Xml blobs that follow the Content Type schema.

For example, the AllLists table contains a field tp_ContentTypes which holds the schemas for the content types that are in effect for that list.

Also, the reason Microsoft is so adamant about not performing SELECTS against the database is simply so they have the option to change the database schema without breaking their customers custom reporting or negatively impacting performance.